How can I get the history of Github pull requests body edits using graphql
I was looking into a way to get the edits from a pull request body but I couldn't find a way through rest nor graphic. Is there a way to get this history?
Looking at a pull request I see this drop down on the pull request body where I can look through the different changes. I want to use this to fix some problems with pr templates we have with renovate bot. Obviously this should be fixed there but I'm looking for an alternative until this is fixed.
enter image description here
I was looking through the documentation of pullRequest timelineItems but I couldn't find something matching.
